# Custom Listview in android application with images and texts

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I have created database in external storage and i have stored image path and  audio paths for each step in tables. Now from a new android application i want to access the table and extract in custom listview with image and text. Image are stored in a form of string in table. How do i get the image and view in custom listview?

Comment: With a database query and a custom adapter.

Comment: Can i add button in listview with function of playing different audios in llistview

Comment: yes you can add any view in your listview.

Comment: Of course. Create your own view with a button. Then add a listener to this button to play a sound. https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/

Answer (score 0):

```
static DisplayImageOptions op;
static ImageLoader loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
```

In your onCreate

```
op = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20)).cacheOnDisc(true)
            .considerExifParams(true).build();

ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customwhateverlist);
String query = "SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE with whatever you want  ";

Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);

((ListView) list).setAdapter(new MyCallitwhatyouwillAdapter(context,cursor, 0));
```

THEN...

```
private static final class MyCallItWhatYouWillAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    MyCallitwhatyouwillAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, flags);

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.SOMECOOLLAYOUT, parent, false);
        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.YOURIMAGETHINGEE);
        //FOR IMAGELOADER YOU MUST HAVE "_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" in database!!!
        TextView blah = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id._id);
        blah.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("SomethingNiceColumn")));
loader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));  
   loader.displayImage(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("SavedPathToImage")), iv, op);
    }


    LayoutInflater mInflater;
}
```

and you will need to add imageloader as a library. You can get it here.
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: what is op in the code ?

Comment: op is just the optional display options for imageloader to load your image in a certain format. I believe it helps avoid out of memory errors.